# Cassandra Partition key duplicates?

Tags: cassandra

I am new to Cassandra so I had a few quick questions, suppose I do this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_keyspace.my_table (
 id bigint,     
 year int,   
 datetime timestamp,    
 field1 int,     
 field2 int,
 PRIMARY KEY ((id, year), datetime))
```

I imagine Cassandra as something like `Map<PartitionKey, SortedMap<ColKey, ColVal>>`,

My question is when querying for something from Cassandra using a WHERE, it will be like:

`SELECT * FROM my_keyspace.my_table WHERE id = 1 AND year = 4`,

This could return **2 or more records**, how does this fit in with the data model of Cassandra?

If it really it a Big HashMap how come duplicate records for a `partition key` are allowed?

Thanks!

Comment: in any DB, PRIMARY_KEY is unique identifier of a record, you can't have more than 1 records with exact same (id, year & datetime),  In your case datetime must be different.

Answer (score 3):

There is a batch of entries in the `SortedMap<ColKey, ColVal>` for each row, using its sorted nature.

To build on your mental model, while there is only 1 partition key for `id = 1 AND year = 4` there are multiple cells:

```
(id, year) |  ColKey            | ColVal
------------------------------------------
 1, 4      | datetime(1):field1 | 1         \ Row1
 1, 4      | datetime(1):field2 | 2         / 
 1, 4      | datetime(5):field1 | 1         \ 
 1, 4      | datetime(5):field2 | 2         / Row2
...
```

Comment: Can you explain whats `datetime(1)` vs `datetime(5)`?

Comment: to show that its the datetime field which helps if table schema changes. If using `COMPACT STORAGE` in pre 3.0 it would literally be ne `1:field1` `1:field2` for one row where the datetime is set to 1 and `5:field1`, `5:field2` for the row where datetime is 5. Basically taking advantage of the `SortedMap` ordering.